# Communicating with different services at the same time

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently developing an android app to control Arduino. BLE delivers a few services. First service has characteristic to WRITE and rest of services has characteristics to READ.

I must WRITE data constantly and READ from time to time.
GATT can do one operation at the same time...
What is the best solution to achieve this?

Comment: yes in BLE thats the issue after one characteristic success you can read or write another charactristic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to modify the Arduino firmware? Then maybe you should change it to send Notifications instead of using Read Request. Then you can send a Notification at any time.

Also consider using Write Without Response, since you don't have to wait for a Write Response from the peripheral before you can send another packet. However you still need to wait for the onCharacteristicWrite callback in Android before you can send another request (write/read) but that will usually be called immediately unless the packet queue is full.

Also what do you mean with "Write data constantly", is that at a regular interval or really constantly (write another packet as soon as you get the write response)?